# Changing the order of entries for a geopandas choropleth map legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, geopandas, choropleth

I am plotting a certain categorical value over the map of a city. The line of code I use to plot is the following:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = plt.gca()
urban_data.plot(column="category", cmap="viridis", ax=ax, categorical=True, /
                k=4, legend=True, linewidth=0.5, /
                legend_kwds={'fontsize':'19', 'loc':'lower left'})
```

where urban data is a geopandas dataframe, and I am using matplotlib as plotting library. The argument `legend_kwds` allows me to control minor things on the legend, like the position or the font size, but I cannot decide major things like, for example, the order of the entries in the legend box. In fact my categories are ranked, let's say 1-2-3-4, but I always get them displayed in a different order.

Is it possible to have more control over the legend? For example by calling it *outside* the `gdf.plot()` function? And, if so, how do I match the colors in the legend with those in the map, which are discrete values (that I don't know exactly) of a viridis colormap?

---

EDIT: here is a verifiable example. Unfortunately shapefiles need other files to work, and here a `geometry` (an area, not a point) column is needed, so I have to ask you to download [this shpfile](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/USA_adm.zip) of the US. Everything you need is within this folder. Here's the code to reproduce the issue. The plot in output is bad because I did not care about the coordinates system here, but the important thing is the legend.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gdf=gpd.read_file('.../USA_adm1.shp')
clusters=np.random.randint(0,4, size=52)
gdf['cluster']=clusters
clusdict={1: 'lower-middle', 2: 'upper-middle', 3: 'upper', 0: 'lower'}
gdf['cluster']=gdf['cluster'].map(clusdict)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = plt.gca()
gdf.plot(column='cluster',cmap='viridis', categorical=True, legend=True, ax=ax)
```

Comment: When you say "I always get them displayed in a different order", what does this order depend on? If it is the occurance of the categories in the dataframe, you can probably just sort it to your liking before plotting.

Comment: My guess is that entires are sorted in alphabetical order (because they are), but I have no idea about how to control this. In the gdf they're all mixed.

Comment: I fear you need to provide some [mcve] here. Maybe [this](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) can be adjusted to your case?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a verifiable example. Unfortunately there is a file to download, but after that it's pretty straightforward to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, great. What is your desired order in the legend now? Does it have to do with the numbers 0 to 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bad news is that categories in legends produced by geopandas are sorted and this is hardcoded ([see source-code here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/ddaa26fdba668a9afb53d9fd86158e6d25dc5ead/geopandas/plotting.py#L449)).

One solution is hence to have the categorical column such that if it is sorted, it would correspond to the desired order. Using integers seems fine for that. Then one can replace the names in the legend, once it is produced in the correct order.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gdf=gpd.read_file('data/USA_adm/USA_adm1.shp')
clusters=np.random.randint(0,4, size=52)
gdf['cluster']=clusters
clusdict={1: 'lower-middle', 2: 'upper-middle', 3: 'upper', 0: 'lower'}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = plt.gca()
gdf.plot(column='cluster',cmap='viridis', categorical=True, legend=True, ax=ax)

def replace_legend_items(legend, mapping):
    for txt in legend.texts:
        for k,v in mapping.items():
            if txt.get_text() == str(k):
                txt.set_text(v)

replace_legend_items(ax.get_legend(), clusdict)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, cool. So if the desired order in is not 0-1-2-3 (bc, for example, these are categories that outputs from a clustering algorithm, that don't assign them with a ranking purpose) the solution would be to identify the ranking by myself and then to apply this function 2 times: the first to assign 0-1-2-3 labels ranking-wise, so that the legend becomes a record of sorted integers, and then again to give the desired names to the now sorted labels. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I had to alter the accepted answer (the second line in the function) from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest a bit to get it to work (maybe there have been updates since),

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gdf=gpd.read_file('data/USA_adm/USA_adm1.shp')
clusters=np.random.randint(0,4, size=52)
gdf['cluster']=clusters
clusdict={1: 'lower-middle', 2: 'upper-middle', 3: 'upper', 0: 'lower'}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = plt.gca()
gdf.plot(column='cluster',cmap='viridis', categorical=True, legend=True, ax=ax)

def replace_legend_items(legend, mapping):
    for txt in legend.get_texts():
        for k,v in mapping.items():
            if txt.get_text() == str(k):
                txt.set_text(v)

replace_legend_items(ax.get_legend(), clusdict)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have 4 legends, you can do the following to set them in whatever order you like. The following code shows how to put them in the following order (using index): 0, 2, 3, 1.

Here `ax` is the axis object which you have define using `ax = plt.gca()`

```
handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [handles[0], handles[2], handles[3], handles[1]]
labels = [labels[0], labels[2], labels[3], labels[1]]
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

Let me give you an example:

**Default order**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(5)
plt.plot(x, x, label=r'$y=x$')
plt.plot(x, 2*x, label=r'$y=2x$')
plt.plot(x, 3*x, label=r'$y=3x$')
plt.plot(x, 4*x, label=r'$y=4x$')
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```

[image]

**Manually changed order**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(5)
plt.plot(x, x, label=r'$y=x$')
plt.plot(x, 2*x, label=r'$y=2x$')
plt.plot(x, 3*x, label=r'$y=3x$')
plt.plot(x, 4*x, label=r'$y=4x$')

handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [handles[0], handles[2],handles[3], handles[1]]
labels = [labels[0], labels[2], labels[3], labels[1]]
ax.legend(handles, labels, fontsize=16)
```

One can also use list comprehension using a pre-specified order list as

```
order = [0, 2, 3, 1]
handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [handles[i] for i in order]
labels = [labels[i] for i in order]
ax.legend(handles, labels, fontsize=16)
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`, but it returns empty lists. Probably because the legend here is not an `ax` attribute, but it is invoked with `legend=True` in the plot function. But I am not sure about that. Only thing certain is that handles and labels are empty lists.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: eh. It's not easy because I cannot share the data, and creating a "dummy" geodataframe is not immediate. I'll try it in a while

Comment: I added a verifiable example.