# matplotlib assign color to categorical variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, categorical-data

I've created map with geopandas plotting speed of sale of property. In dataframe I've got categorical variable with possible values: very bad, bad, medium, good, very good distributed among all counties. And it works, howewer after plotting, with for example 'Reds' counties with very bad and very good are colored with similar shade of red (of course not the same but almost). Meaning, ther are not order as I would expect from the brightest to the most red.
I changed this variable to pd.categorical (which works for grouping) but it didn't help.

Is there possibility to assign color in plot() function to specific value?

Comment: Here I found answer for my trouble:https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/735

Comment: another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370302/changing-the-order-of-entries-for-a-geopandas-choropleth-map-legend